# Why does my generated Button look weird?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, properties

I started programming C# & Winforms on Monday and only used java before. So i try to generate a Button and it should look like a Button which is already there, but there is a weird grey box around it and it hides the button image. When i click on the button, the color changes and reveals the image of the button.

Heres my Code and the buttons:

code

[image]

first row how it should be, third when selected

[image]

Comment: Better not post screenshots of your code but the actual code.

Comment: And please stick to English, I've no idea what a Druecken is for example

Comment: just the name of the image for the button, the names are chosen by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the "location" you create a new Point()
and there you are using bRichtungI0.Location.X and yLocation2. Are you sure that there's not another variable for the y part in your code? Just thoughts...
And why are you generating the Button on your own when Visual Studio can do this for you in WinForms?